# iOS+Android SDK for custom keyboard dictionaries and prediction and autocorrect logic

Tags: android, ios, dictionary, keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard for iOS and Android and I'm looking to source the dictionaries ( English, French, Portuguese, and Turkish) and the prediction and autocorrect logic.   Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So, what must the SDk provide you with?

Comment: from either Objective C and from Java I would like to call a simple api where I would pass the context around the text insertion point, i.e. what the user is typing  and any previous words typed,  and the api would return a list of suggestions ordered by a "score" based on the most likely thing the user wants to enter.

Comment: The api should also allow me to communicate to the sdk the user's current keyboard language choice.   And probably the sdk should be able to learn and restore the suggestions based on what the user has previously entered.   I'd like all of the wordlists and search logic to be encapsulated behind the api.   I have been searching the internet and have not found anything suitable so far.

Comment: I see! Please include that info in the body of your question, thanks! Comments get deleted.